# Use List as monad in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm wondering what is idiomatic way to applying some operation on the `List` if it is not empty, and return empty `List` (`Nil`) if list is empty.

```
  val result= myList match  {
     case Nil => Nil // this one looks bad for me
     case nonEmpty =>  myService.getByFilters(nonEmpty)
  }
```

Just using `map` operation on the list will trigger loop, but I want to achieve same result as `map` for `Option` type - i.e. do something only once if `List` is non-empty, and do nothing if `List` is empty

Comment: Note that it is not really correct to say "use list as monad" in this context. List monad has a particular definition and its `fmap` function is `map`. Something else won't be neither a monad nor a functor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your design is not quite right perhaps. You should be just able to pass any list into the `getByFilters` function and it should just handle lists of any length. So there should be no need for these sorts of checks.

If the design change is not possible there is nothing wrong with `if`:

```
val result = if(myList.isEmpty) Nil else myService.getByFilters(myList)
```

It's idiomatic because `if` returns values. Maybe there are other clean ways, I don't know.

If you just want to require non empty list argument you can use `HList` or  alternatively, you can use this trick:

```
def takesNonEmptyList[T](head: T, tail: T *): List[T] = head :: tail.toList
```

You can do something fake to make it seem look idiomatic, but I would not recommend it. It's unclear and unnecessary complication:

```
def getByFilters(xs: List[Int]) = xs.filter(_ % 2 == 0)
val res = l.headOption.map(_ :: l.tail).map(getByFilters).getOrElse(Nil)
println(res)
```

prints `List(2, 4)`

Comment: Yes, I thought about moving this logic in `myService#getByFilters`, but then decided that it is not correct to return empty list from this method, because  in case of empty list parameter list (list of filters) it will return ALL values without applying filter. So I decided it's more correct to throw exception inside `myService#getByFilters` if list is empty. And caring about empty list of parameters is responsobility of client code

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it, you can just implement your own semantic:

```
  implicit class MySpecialList[T](xs: List[T]) {
    def mapIfNotEmpty[R](f: List[T] ⇒ List[R]): List[R] =
      if (xs.isEmpty) Nil else f(xs)
  }

  def getStuff(xs: List[Int]) = xs.map(_ + " OK")

  val x: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
  val y: List[Int] = List()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val xx = x.mapIfNotEmpty(getStuff) // List("1 OK", "2 OK", "3 OK")
    val yy = y.mapIfNotEmpty(getStuff) // List()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is method `headOption` in `List`, so you could use option semantic to lift `List` to `Option[List]`:

```
import scala.collection.TraversableLike

implicit class TraversableOption[T <: TraversableLike[_, T]](traversable: T) {
  def opt: Option[T] = traversable.headOption.map(_ => traversable)
}
```

you can use it as:

```
val result = myList.opt.fold[List[Int]](Nil)(myService.getByFilters)
```

Answer (score 0):

By invoking each filter service separately,

```
myList.flatMap(filter => myService.getByFilters(List(filter)))
```

it gets an empty list if `myList` is empty. If performance may be a matter, consider also a parallel version with

```
myList.par
```